# Pre-focus input box before fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textinput

I have two `input` fields. The second `input` starts focused. I then want to `fadeOut` both `input`s, having the second `input` staying focused until the end. Finally, I want to `fadeIn` both `input`s and end up with the *first* `input` focused.

However, I do not want to see a "glitch", when the second `input` gets focused for an instant after `fadeIn` completes, and then the first `input` focuses immediately after.

This is what I have tried (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6t2y2/3/)):

```
// Focus the second input field
$('input').eq(1).focus();

// Fade out both input fields
$('div').fadeOut();

// Fade in both input fields
$('div').fadeIn(function () {
    // Causes a "transition glitch"
    $('input').eq(0).focus();
});
```

​Is there a way to "pre-focus" the second `input` field?

Comment: Can you just move your callback to focus in `the $('div').fadeOut();` instead the `fadeIn`?

Comment: @GabrielGartz no, because hidden (display: none) elements cannot receive focus

Comment: Uhm, if fade works just with opacity works, but you are right. So he can do it right after call the fadeIn instead wait for finish, because the fadeIn will do a display block without opacity and then start effect to change opacity.

Comment: @GabrielGartz yes, if done _immediately_ and not as part of the callback, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
// Focus the second input field
$('input').eq(1).focus();

// Fade out both input fields
$('div').animate({'opacity': 0}, function() {
    $('input').eq(0).focus();

    // Fade in both input fields
    $('div').animate({'opacity': 1});​
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather, than using `fadeout` which changes the `display` property to `none` (and preventing focus), you can `animate` the `opacity`:

```
// Focus the second input field
$('input').eq(1).focus();

// Fade out both input fields
$('div').animate({opacity: 0}, function () {
    // focus the first field once they are invisible
    $('input').eq(0).focus();
});

// Fade in both input fields
$('div').animate({opacity: 1});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

The trick is you can't set focus to an element that is not rendering in the dom (`display: none` happens after fadeOut). so after the fade out finishes, make it visible, focus, invisible, then fade in. There will be no flicker because the DOM manipulations in the function all happen before the browser renders.

```
// Focus the second input field
$('input').eq(1).focus();

// Fade out both input fields
$('div').fadeOut(500, function() {
    // Make the input visible in the dom
    $('div').show();
    // set the focus
    $('input').eq(0).focus();
    // make it invisible again, then start the fade in
    $('div').hide().fadeIn();
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5faq/2/

Or you animate opacity instead of fading out